Artifically creating Barrier option
I am looking for some insights on how a Barrier option payoff can be replicated either with Plain vanilla options.
In Chapter 25, Hull has provided one such example to replicate a Up and Out Barrier option with boundary at 60 and strike at 50 and maturity 0.75 years.
He suggested portfolio of call options where first 2 call options has strike 50 and 60 and bother are maturing at 0.75. The remaining options have maturities in other time points like 0.50 and 0.25.
I wonder how this strategy can replicate Barrier option payoff at 0.75? For example if at 0.75, underlying's price is > 60, then Barrier option has zero value. However the replicating portfolio, which has call options with strikes 50 and 60, will be ITM both.
Could you please help how exactly this works?
Any insight and/or online reference can be very helpful.
Thanks for your time.

Unfortunately I could not find the reference to the replication in my version of Hull, but I will try to explain the replication argument that matches up with what you describe.
Let's first look at the payoff of the option $C_{uo}$ at expiration and assume that the asset price $S$ has not hit the barrier:
$$
C_{uo}(S) =
\begin{cases}
0, S < 50 \text{ or } S>60 \\
S - 50, \text{ else }
\end{cases}
$$
This payoff can be replicated by buying a call option with strike 50 and selling a call option with strike 60.
Now you have to have a look at the cases where the asset is above the barrier before expiration: The up and out option becomes worthless. This is why you need to hold options at earlier points in time to replicate this payoff (although I don't think it can be replicated (at least not static) using only vanilla options).
